# cakePHP 3.0 pre-populate database - migrations

Tags: mysql, cakephp, migration, entity, cakephp-3.0

I have an existing database. With this command I made my migration file:

```
bin/cake bake migration_snapshot Initial
```

Now I'd like to pre-populate the database, mu guess is that it should be done in this migration file but can't find an example online.

In the overview section of the link below I read it should be possible to insert data into the database by using migrations.

> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html

**Example**

Add Column

```
$user = $this->table('users', ['id' => false, 'primary_key' => ['user_id']]);
    $user
        ->addColumn('user_id', 'integer', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 11,
            'null' => false,
        ])
->create();
```

Populate *(This doesn't work)*

```
$user = TableRegistry::get('Users')->newEntity();
$user = TableRegistry::get('Users')->newEntity([
      'user_id' => 1,
   ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use update instead of create when updating a db via migration

```
$user = $this->table('users', ['id' => false, 'primary_key' => ['user_id']]);
$user
    ->addColumn('user_id', 'integer', [
        'default' => null,
        'limit' => 11,
        'null' => false,
    ])
   ->update();
```

and use

```
bin/cake migrations migrate
```

Comment: Isn't ->update(); used when you change a column name?

Comment: we are attributing here that table's structure is changed , what you were earlier using would try to create a another table with same name which is not possible and will throw errors